Extract *all* possible patterns in a variable
I have a large variable containing strings (words). I need to extract all substrings that contain any of the patters listed in a separate vector.
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Word = c("hope", "freeze", "free"))

patterns <- "hope|freeze|free|du|li|un|de|em|bi|en|im|ro|gi|ai|ag|wo|ab|di|ac|eu|ic|se|al|ob|ig|es|ef|sy|ep|ec|y|u|e|o|a|h|i"

df %>%
  mutate(simple = str_extract_all(Word, patterns))

However, it looks like the function returns the most complete string depending on the order the patterns are in. So, for example, if patterns has the order shown above, the result will be:
    Word simple
1   hope   hope
2 freeze freeze
3   free   free


If the order is reversed (i.e., descending order with respect to length:
patterns2 <-"y|u|e|o|a|h|i|du|li|un|de|em|bi|en|im|ro|gi|ai|ag|wo|ab|di|ac|eu|ic|se|al|ob|ig|es|ef|sy|ep|ec|hope|freeze|free"

df %>%
  mutate(simple = str_extract_all(Word, patterns2))

  Word   simple
1   hope h, o, e
2 freeze  freeze
3   free    free

Is there a way to get all potential patterns, regardless of the order of the patterns? Here's the desired output:
    Word  simple
1   hope  h, o, e, hope
2 freeze  freeze
3   free    free


Regex alone in a generic scenario like here cannot be used to extract matches that share the same start location.

Just as in the linked thread, do not use a single | based regex, run each substring search separately.

You can split the pattern into a vector of sub-patterns, and then extract the elements included in each word.
pat_vec <- str_split_1(patterns, fixed('|'))

df %>%
  mutate(simple = lapply(Word, \(x) pat_vec[str_which(x, pat_vec)]))

#     Word          simple
# 1   hope   hope, e, o, h
# 2 freeze freeze, free, e
# 3   free         free, e

